# Heat Transfer and Heat added to a system

Tags: thermodynamics

Let's say the temperature of an object is constant and equal to 20 °C. If we put this object to a surrounding which has a temperature of 25 °C, than there's heat transfer from the surrounding to object by convection. If $q$ is the heat transfer (in Watt) than after a specific time ($Δ$t) we will have Temperature of the object equal to 25 °C ( If we consider the temperature of the surrounding constant) and thus we will have a net heat transfer equal to $Q = qxΔt$ if $q$ is constant. My question is, if we consider a 1D heat transfer, the surface of the object exposed to the surrounding will get the heat and thus will receive each $dt$ the amount of heat $q$ ($q$ is measured like a current, in a cross section of the object) then will gain as internal energy $\Delta U = q$ but we say that all the object gained the heat $q$ not only the surface exposed to the surrounding. Can we say, first the surface of the object exposed will gain an internal energy equal to $q$ (increasing its temperature) and thus "distributing" its energy "uniformly" to the other parts of the object so we can say that all the object gained $\Delta U$ as energy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say the temperature of an object is constant and equal to 20 °C. If we put this object to a surrounding which has a temperature of 25 °C, than there's heat transfer from the surrounding to object by convection. If $q$ is the heat transfer (in Watt) than after a specific time ($Δt$) we will have Temperature of the object equal to 25 °C.

This is not entirely correct.

Take an object of mass $m$ and heat capacity $c_p$ at an initial temperature $T_0$. At $t=0$ we place it in surroundings of constant $T_s (> T_0)$.

Heat now starts to flow from the surroundings to the object. In an infinitesimal amunt of time $dt$ with Newton's heating/cooling Law:

$dq=kA(T_s-T(t))dt$, where $k$ is the heat transfer coefficient, $A$ the surface area of the object and $T(t)$ the instantaneous temperature of the object.

This increment in Enthalpy $dq$ raises the temperature of the object by $dT$ acc.:

$dq=mc_pdT(t)$.

So we have:

$mc_pdT(t)=kA(T_s-T(t))dt$, a differential equation where variables can be separated.

Integrated between $t=0, T_0$ and $t, T(t)$ we get:

$T(t)=T_s-(T_s-T_0)e^{-\alpha t}$, with $\alpha=\frac{kA}{mc_p}$.

What this shows is that $T(t)=T_s$ only for $t \to +\infty$ because only then does $e^{-\alpha t} \to 0$.

So in reality $\Delta t= +\infty$! This is a very frequent outcome in this kind of heating/cooling situations.

As regards:

> Can we say, first the surface of the object exposed will gain an internal energy equal to q (increasing its temperature) and thus "distributing" its energy "uniformly" to the other parts of the object so we can say that all the object gained $ΔU$ as energy?

The outer surface layer of the object first heats up but the Enthalpy it absorbed then flows from that hotter surface to deeper, colder parts by means of *heat conduction*. The object thus has a *heat gradient* ($\frac{dT}{dx}$, in the $x$ direction for example) from its boundary to its core. Over time that gradient flattens, until the object has a homogeneous temperature.

It's not really necessary to use Internal energy here: as no work is being performed: $\Delta U = q$.